# Not able to open url during script run in real device on ios 10.2 with Appium 1.6.3, Webview timeout issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ios

**Environment**

Appium Verion => 1.6.3

JDK => 8.0

ios => 10.2

Xcode => 8.0

**Appium Console Error**

```
Last login: Wed Dec 28 12:05:16 on ttys002
test1:~ vbsmac$ appium -p 4727
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   port: 4727
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4727
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"safariIgnoreFraudWarning":true,"platformVersion":"10.2","safariAllowPopups":false,"browserName":"Safari","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"iOS","udid":"d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6","deviceName":"hchanders iPad"}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"safariIgnoreFraudWarning":true,"platformVersion":"10.2","safariAllowPopups":false,"browserName":"Safari","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"iOS","udid":"d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6","deviceName":"hchanders iPad"},null,null,null,null]
[Appium] Requested iOS support with version >= 10, using XCUITest driver instead of UIAutomation-based driver, since the latter is unsupported on iOS 10 and up.
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   safariIgnoreFraudWarning: true
[Appium]   platformVersion: '10.2'
[Appium]   safariAllowPopups: false
[Appium]   browserName: 'Safari'
[Appium]   autoWebview: 'true'
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   udid: 'd83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'hchanders iPad'
[debug] [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.4.2
[BaseDriver] Capability 'autoWebview' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '8.2'
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.2'
[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6
[debug] [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: 'd83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6', real device: true
[XCUITest] Safari test requested
[debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
[debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog'
[XCUITest] Setting up real device
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: /usr/local/bin/carthage
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Using real device logger 'idevicesyslog'
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build test -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6 -configuration Debug' in directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[debug] [XCUITest] Unable to get device time. Using local system time
[debug] [XCUITest] Output from idevicedate: Wed Dec 28 12:44:41 IST 2016

[XCUITest] Waiting for WebDriverAgent to start on device
[debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/vbsmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/F3630FFD-2C61-47A8-B279-423EB2224E8B/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2016-12-28_124442-hSx2Kw.log
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Dec 28 12:44:47 hchanders-iPad XCTRunner[2728] <Notice>: Running tests...
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Dec 28 12:44:49 hchanders-iPad XCTRunner[2728] <Notice>: Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
[XCUITest] Detected that WebDriverAgent is running at url 'http://192.168.1.227:8100'
[XCUITest] WebDriverAgent started at url 'http://192.168.1.227:8100'
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting iproxy to forward traffic from local port 8100 to device port 8100 over USB
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.apple.mobilesafari","arguments":["-u","http://appium.io"],"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true}}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"8E0ED454-A5F0-4B42-B486-CA73E4C256E9","capabilities":{"device":"ipad","browserName":"Safari","sdkVersion":"10.2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.mobilesafari"}},"sessionId":"8E0ED454-A5F0-4B42-B486-CA73E4C256E9","status":0}
[debug] [XCUITest] Setting initial orientation to 'PORTRAIT'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /orientation] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/8E0ED454-A5F0-4B42-B486-CA73E4C256E9/orientation] with body: {"orientation":"PORTRAIT"}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{},"sessionId":"8E0ED454-A5F0-4B42-B486-CA73E4C256E9","status":0}
[debug] [XCUITest] Waiting for initial webview
[debug] [iOS] Waiting for 3000 ms before navigating to view.
[debug] [iOS] Navigating to most recently opened webview
[debug] [iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
[debug] [iOS] Selecting by url: true (expected url: 'http://appium.io')
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Getting WebKitRemoteDebugger pageArray: localhost, 27753
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending request to: http://localhost:27753/json
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page element JSON: [{"devtoolsFrontendUrl":"/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:27753/devtools/page/3","faviconUrl":"","thumbnailUrl":"/thumb/http://bkstr-tablet-q1.uat.brandingbrand.com/","title":"Branding Brand","url":"http://bkstr-tablet-q1.uat.brandingbrand.com/","webSocketDebuggerUrl":"ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/3","appId":"PID:2736"},{"devtoolsFrontendUrl":"/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:27753/devtools/page/4","faviconUrl":"","thumbnailUrl":"/thumb/http://appium.io/","title":"Appium: Mobile App Automation Made Awesome.","url":"http://appium.io/","webSocketDebuggerUrl":"ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/4","appId":"PID:2734"}]
[debug] [iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
[debug] [iOS] Selecting by url: true (expected url: 'http://appium.io')
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Getting WebKitRemoteDebugger pageArray: localhost, 27753
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending request to: http://localhost:27753/json
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page element JSON: [{"devtoolsFrontendUrl":"/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:27753/devtools/page/3","faviconUrl":"","thumbnailUrl":"/thumb/http://bkstr-tablet-q1.uat.brandingbrand.com/","title":"Branding Brand","url":"http://bkstr-tablet-q1.uat.brandingbrand.com/","webSocketDebuggerUrl":"ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/3","appId":"PID:2736"},{"devtoolsFrontendUrl":"/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:27753/devtools/page/4","faviconUrl":"","thumbnailUrl":"/thumb/http://appium.io/","title":"Appium: Mobile App Automation Made Awesome.","url":"http://appium.io/","webSocketDebuggerUrl":"ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/4","appId":"PID:2734"}]
[debug] [iOS] Picking webview 'WEBVIEW_3'
[debug] [iOS] Attempting to set context to 'WEBVIEW_3'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] WebKit debugger web socket connected to url: ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/3
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Unregistering from page readiness notifications
[Appium] New XCUITestDriver session created successfully, session c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7 added to master session list
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"Safari","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"safariIgnoreFraudWarning":true,"platformVersion":"10.2","safariAllowPopups":false,"autoWebview":"true","platformName":"iOS","udid":"d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6","deviceName":"hchanders iPad"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 22943 ms - 480 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts {"type":"implicit","ms":50000}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: ["implicit",50000,"c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'timeouts'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 50000ms
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts 200 13 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts {"type":"page load","ms":9000000}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: ["page load",9000000,"c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'timeouts'
[debug] [iOS] Set page load timeout to 9000000ms
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts 200 3 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts {"type":"script","ms":9000000}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: ["script",9000000,"c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'timeouts'
[debug] [iOS] Set async script timeout to 9000000ms
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/timeouts 200 4 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/url {"url":"http://bkstr-tablet-qa1.uat.bbhosted.com/9969store/home"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.setUrl() with args: ["http://bkstr-tablet-qa1.uat.bbhosted.com/9969store/home","c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'setUrl'
[debug] [iOS] Attempting to set url 'http://bkstr-tablet-qa1.uat.bbhosted.com/9969store/home'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Navigating to new URL: http://bkstr-tablet-qa1.uat.bbhosted.com/9969store/home
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending WebKit data: {"method":"Page.navigate","...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Receiving WebKit data: {"result":{},"id":1}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found handler for message '1'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page navigated message: {"result":{},"id":1}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Waiting for dom...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page loaded, verifying whether ready
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Checking document readyState
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command (function (){ return document.readyState; })()
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending WebKit data: {"method":"Runtime.evaluate...
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: TimeoutError: operation timed out
    at afterTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/timers.js:16:15)
    at Timeout.timeoutTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/timers.js:59:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c2b529f4-a013-4eb0-940b-329983ed0ce7/url 500 8057 ms - 190 
[debug] [iProxy] recv failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
[debug] [iProxy] recv failed: Operation not permitted
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] WebKit remote debugger socket disconnected
```

**Eclipse Console Error**

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: operation timed out (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```